# git checkout file for multiple files not staged for commit

Tags: git, git-checkout

If `git status` reports 10 files not staged for commit and would like to revert changes to them using one command instead of multiple `git checkout single_file`.
Is it possible?

Comment: You mean `reset`? (Of course a great deal depends on (1) what you think "disable changes" means, and (2) whether there also other files you _don't_ want to "disable changes" to.)

Comment: there are additional files which i'll stage and commit. "disable changes" means revert, undo.

Comment: So use the `git reset --soft` or the clean command

Comment: I think you are looking for `git checkout .`

Comment: thanks `git checkout .` helped me

Comment: "there are additional files which i'll stage and commit" So you will either have to list all the files that you _want_ to stage and commit or all the files you _don't_ want to stage and commit. How else will `git` know which files are which? It can't read your mind. And that being so, what does it matter which set you have to list? Maybe you would just be happier using a decent GUI.

Comment: i decided to perform `git checkout .` , to ignore the changes to other files as well, it's easier

Comment: @user1264304: *ignore* is the wrong verb here: `git checkout .` means "extract files from the index to the working-tree, using the pathspec `.`". That copies the files out of the index into the work-tree, so that the work-tree version now matches the index version. The files copied are all of those that are (a) *in* the index and (b) in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git clean` && `git reset`

```
# Upper X - remove only ignored files
git clean –Xfd  []

# small x - remove untracked
git clean –xfd  

# discard all changes in working dir & staging are 
git reset HEAD --hard
```

> ... like to disable changes

If you need to modify them but you want git to ignore your changes use the `assume-unchanged` option

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

### `--[no-]assume-unchanged`

> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>
> Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

[image]